# On windows, how to prevent registry entries from being modified?

Tags: windows, winapi

I saw some anti-virus software notice me that some other process was trying to modify my registry entry and ask me whether to allow it. How can this anti-virus software hang that process up and stop if from modifying my registry until I make a decision? I fail to find any API that could do such things, which is crucial for my project.

Thanks,

Feng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The antivirus is most likely hooking the registry functions so it's own code gets called first before passing the requests to the real functions.

Note that doing this in anything but a few very specific circumstances can be suspicious behaviour.

Comment: So, by hooking the registry functions, you mean that the AV software has injected its code into every process ever created?

Comment: Either that or patching the Kernel service table. `Every kernel service that’s exported for use by Windows applications has a pointer in a table that’s indexed with the internal service number Windows assigns to the API. If a driver replaces an entry in the table with a pointer to its own function then the kernel invokes the driver function any time an application executes the API and the driver can control the behavior of the API.` [Source](https://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2005/10/31/sony-rootkits-and-digital-rights-management-gone-too-far.aspx?Redirected=true)

Comment: Patching the "Kernel Service Table" is NOT COOL (tm), NOT SUPPORTED, and cannot be done on x64 variants of Windows (PatchGuard will panic the machine).  My answer below contains the only supported method for registry event filtering.

Answer (score 2):

This is done with games too. They hijack function calls which render objects in a 3D scene, they then tell the game engine to render all characters on top of every other object, which results in a wallhack.

An API you could use for this (not anymore since anti-cheat software blocks it now) is the detours API. You can still use it for your own purposes ofcourse.

There's alot of information about this API on the web.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/

Answer (score 2):

Consider properly securing your applications registry keys using [RegSetKeySecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (MSDN).

Alternately, you could also construct a registry filter kernel mode driver.  Such a driver can utilize the [CmRegisterCallback/Ex()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) service to filter registry events.  This is a *big job* (tm), but is the only documented/supported method to accomplish this that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could have a look at [RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I think a antivirus won't use this approach. This does **not** block changes made to the registry, but could be used to get notified **when** a key is modified.

Comment: Indeed `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` will not block changes. The AV software must be using a driver to intercept the APIs (as ProcessMonitor does to be able to give far more details about the operations such as calling process's call stack).